# Fuse C++ driver - read() implementation

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, driver, fuse

I'm trying to implement a FUSE driver.
What I've done, is taken the basic operations that you override with your own function, and I've added a `cout << operation << path << endl;` So I can see which operation gets called. Here is my `open` function:

```
int Router::open(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi) {
  std::cout << "open " << path << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This returns `0` so the open should succeed all the time.
Then, here is my `read` function:

```
int Router::read(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi) {
  std::cout << "read " << path << "Size: " << size << "Offset: " << offset << std::endl;
  buf[0] = 'h';
  buf[1] = '\0';
  return 2;
}
```

This should copy over `h\0` to the buffer.
But when I do: `cat myfile` it runs my `open()` function, which succeeds, then it runs my `read()` function, but the output of cat is nothing. It should output `h` but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Also I find that under OSX, the exact same code only runs the `open` function, but never the `read()`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

So my problem was that in the function: `getattr(...)` I did not specify the file size.
After doing: `st->st_size = 4096;` Everything was working fine :)